# How to measure pipeline latency?

Tags: c++, windows, performance-testing, video-processing, ms-media-foundation

I want to measure how much time does it take MF to process my video samples.

I’ve tried using sample time as unique sample identifier, discovered the pipeline adjusts that value so it drifts away (not fast, 0-1 100-nanoseconds ticks per frame, but even off-by-1 is sufficient for the value to be worthless as a unique ID).

I’ve tried putting custom value in attributes, works OK on Win10 with nVidia encoder, fails on Win7 with MS encoder: the output frame doesn’t contain my value, apparently the encoder dropped all attributes from samples. Tried MFSampleExtension_DeviceTimestamp built-in attribute, same result, the value is lost in the pipelines.

Any other way to match input samples with output samples? Manually counted sequence numbers are too fragile IMO, the framework is heavily multithreaded.

Comment: Did you try MFTrace ?

Comment: @mofo77 It doesn’t have stable sample ID either. It logs addresses of IMFSample interfaces. Input samples and output samples are different objects with different addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You may write a wrapper encoder MFT which wrap MS decoder in Win7, and record the sample times/additional attributes into a queue in IMFTransform::ProcessInput, and process it in IMFTransform::ProcessOutput, and get the attribute according to the sample time, and set the related attributes to the output samples, is it ok?